# Java FX - Cp1252 Character Encoding Error

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, javafx, encoding

So I've been learning how to use JavaFX in Eclipse, and have come across a character encoding error that always occurs on the last character before the class declaration.

Whenever I run the script, a program error appears that says exactly this:

*"Save could not be completed. Try File > Save As... if the problem persists.
Reason:
Some characters cannot be mapped using the "Cp1252" character encoding.
Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding."*

I have tried downloading a different program that supports FX called IntelliJ IDEA, and the same error happened on that program, too. However, I somehow managed to fix this error on IntelliJ by simply rewriting the last import by hand. Unfortunately, fixing this problem didn't seem to be as simple when I used Eclipse. The reason I am using Eclipse instead of just using IntelliJ is that my school computers only use Eclipse.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox; //error appears after the semicolon on this line

public class Main extends Application {

    Scene s1, s2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) {
        Label label1 = new Label("s1");
        Button button1 = new Button("Click for s2");
        button1.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(s2));

        VBox lay1 = new VBox(50);
        lay1.getChildren().addAll(label1, button1);

        s1 = new Scene(lay1, 500, 500);

        Button button2 = new Button("Click for s1");
        button2.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(s1));

        s2 = new Scene(lay1, 300, 250);

        window.setScene(s1);
        window.setTitle("title");
        window.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I copy and paste that line into my text editor, I see that there is a byte order mark character, U+FEFF, after the semicolon.  Try selecting from the semicolon to the end of the line, and replacing it with a typed semicolon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like somehow you are getting a character in the file which can't be represented in the Cp1252 encoding (which can only deal with a limited range of characters).

You could change the encoding of the file to UTF-8 which can deal with just about anything.

To change a single file open the file Properties and the Resource page change the 'Text file encoding' value to UTF-8.

You can also change the default text file encoding for the workspace in the Preferences on the 'General > Workspace' page.

Answer (score 1):

As an example:

I found a special character which was the cause of the issue:

Somewhere in my code was written:

```
//Now blabla Equation n̊1
```

Where the `n̊1` was causing this "Save problems" Error